# Testing Scala Play + Slick: why is it picking the wrong database?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm working on [this github project](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala) that uses Play 2.5.10 and Slick 3.1.1 (the issue can be reproduced there by running `sbt test` but can [also be checked directly in travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala#L557)). I use a Postgres database configuration `default` for development and production. I then use a H2 in memory database called `test` for testing. The `default` database is configured in [`conf/application.conf`](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/master/conf/application.conf) whereas the `test` database is configured in [`conf/application.test.conf`](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/master/conf/application.test.conf).

The problem is that for testing I initialize the database with name `test` but the Application built with `GuiceApplicationBuilder` is still picking up the `default` one.

This line is in my `build.sbt` to pick up the test configuration:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

and this is the content of that file:

```
include "application.conf"

slick.dbs {
  test {
    driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
    db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
    db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL"
    db.username="sa"
    db.password=""
  }
}
```

My `DaoFunSpec` base class looks like this:

```
package dao

import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSpec}
import org.scalatestplus.play.OneAppPerSuite
import play.api.Application
import play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions
import play.api.db.DBApi

abstract class DaoFunSpec extends FunSpec with OneAppPerSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  lazy implicit val db = app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi].database("test")

  override def beforeAll() {
    Evolutions.applyEvolutions(db)
  }

  override def afterAll() {
    Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(db)
  }

  def userDao(implicit app: Application) = {
    Application.instanceCache[UserDao].apply(app)
  }
}
```

Note the line `app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi].database("test")` but still Play tries to connect to the `default` database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok your problem is kinda different (or maybe perhaps a little unexpected). This is the line that causes your headache:

```
dbApi.databases().foreach(runEvolutions)
```

Its in: `ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42`

It's probably self-explanatory :)

Still the problem is more involved. You have two databases actually in your test environment (`default` and `test`). Now this leads to several problems - one of which you see above (evolutions are tried on each of them). Another is that if you want to use differently named db you can't just inject something like that:

```
class UserDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
```

instead you would need to use (AFAIR):

```
class UserDao @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("test") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
```

But in that case you testing becomes more complicated.

It would be all much simpler if:

1) You would extract common configuration to `common.conf`

2) You would change your `application.conf` to something like this:

```
include "common.conf"

slick.dbs {
  default {
    driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
    db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/exampledb?searchpath=public"
    db.user="postgres"
    db.password="postgres"
  }
}
```

3) You would change your `application.test.conf` to something like this:

```
include "common.conf"

slick.dbs {
  default {
    driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
    db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
    db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL"
    db.username="sa"
    db.password=""
  }
}
```

Now the only thing is that you should rather have one set of evolutions (`default`) which is actually not that bad as it would make sure your test db is in sync with your production db (at least in terms of structure).

It's not that above is the only solution. You could still have two differently named db configurations; you would need in such scenario to do some kind of remapping in your `Guilce module` (you would then have one module for prod and one for test - they could inherit from one another and only overwrite certain thing - like e.g. attaching `test` db in place of default one). It's basically a matter of taste.

Comment: Hi Pawel! thank you again! good points! but it still leaves me with the problem that 2.sql is not compatible with H2. This is why I needed the separate test database so it would have its own evolutions folder ... I have searched for play.evolutions.* parameters with a prefix to change the root of the evolutions but there is none. This prefix exists only in the test API `Evolutions.withEvolutions(db, ClassLoaderEvolutionsReader.forPrefix("conf/test/"))` but this is triggered too late or not at all.

Comment: Oh... right. Didn't notice you have two different evolution path because of differences in DB. Right. In that case above may not work for. I believe the other question you asked about disabling evolutions would solve the problem. 

Keep in mind though that having two different evolution paths (test + prod) may prove to be troublesome in the long run... (but that's probably weighting pros & cons of running tests on postgres vs embeded H2).

Comment: Hi Pawel, thank you, very correct! I decided to use Postgres for testing as well. The reason is two fold: it is better to test in the database that the application is going to be ultimately deployed and with Postgres is easier to troubleshoot database issues i.e. by connecting with any client and running selects against it while in H2 is a big problematic connecting with Squirrel ... Ah and another big reason why I chose Postgres, Travis CI can auto-deploy and run a postgres instance for unit testing I got it all working in github.